# How to run gsutil from Scala without the .cmd suffix?

Tags: scala, batch-file, sbt, gsutil

I am trying to run gsutil in Scala, but it doesn't work unless I explicitly put `.cmd` in the code. I don't like this approach, since others I work with use Unix systems. How do I let Scala understand that `gsutil == gsutil.cmd`? I could just write a custom shell script and add that to path, but I'd like a solution that doesn't include scripting.

I have already tried with various environment variables (using IntelliJ, don't know if it's relevant). I have tried adding both `/bin` and `/platform/gsutil` to path, neither works (without .cmd at least). I have also tried giving full path to see if it made a difference, it didn't.

Here is the method that uses gsutil:

```
def readFilesInBucket(ss: SparkSession, bucket: String): DataFrame = {
    import ss.implicits._

    ss.sparkContext.parallelize((s"gsutil ls -l $bucket" !!).split("\n")
        .map(r => r.trim.split("  ")).filter(r => r.length == 3)
        .map(r => (r(0), r(1), r(2)))).toDF(Array("Size", "Date", "File"): _*)
}
```

This is my first ever question on SO, I apologize for any formattic errors there may be.

---

EDIT:
Found out, that even when I write a script like this:

```sh
exec gsutil.cmd "$@"
```

called just `gsutil` in the same folder, it spits out the same error message as before: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gsutil": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`.

It works if I write `gsutil` in git bash, which otherwise didn't work without the script.

Comment: Could this be somehow linked to Windows' `%PATHEXT%` variable?

Comment: Possibly, but I doubt it. My pathext is `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW`, so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: If that code is `CreateProcess`ing then you'll need to specify a program to run it. We normally call our batch files `bat` in Windows. `cmd /c "c:\somefile.bat"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just use a different version whether you're on Windows or *nix system?

Create some helper:

```
object SystemDetector {
  lazy val isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")
}
```

And then just use it like:

```
def readFilesInBucket(ss: SparkSession, bucket: String): DataFrame = {
   import ss.implicits._

   val gsutil = if(SystemDetector.isWindows) "gsutil.cmd" else "gsutil"

   ss.sparkContext.parallelize((s"$gsutil ls -l $bucket" !!).split("\n")
       .map(r => r.trim.split("  ")).filter(r => r.length == 3)
       .map(r => (r(0), r(1), r(2)))).toDF(Array("Size", "Date", "File"): _*)
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, that was pretty much my backup plan, but I'd rather not have something hacky like this, since I don't want to paste this everywhere. I have a gut feeling that there is a nice, simple solution, that only requires some configuration of IntelliJ or Windows. But this will have to do for now. Thanks :)

Comment: You could actually wrap whole `(s"$gsutil ls -l $bucket" !!).split("\n")` into some kind of utility function.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could do that. I'm still considering other options rather than this, since it will be useless in production, but we'll see. Cheers though.

Comment: Ended up doing something like this, easiest solution. Thanks

Comment: For anyone interested: It started causing more problems (IDE-specific) so I ended up switching to their storage library for listing objects in a bucket. This also caused some problems, which I described and found solution for here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56133193/9022841